# Android Sending String from another app

Tags: android, service, android-service, intentfilter, intentservice

I am working on two app, ApplicationA and ApplicationB, ApplicationA send String to ApplicationB,and i am display the receiving string on ApplicationB Activity.now everthing is working fine,when i Click on a Button from ApplicationA and want to send a string to ApplicationB,there is popup appear and i am select the ApplicationB from this popup,i want when i click on Button from ApplicationA the popup does not appear and directly my ApplicationB open and display the recieving string,also i want to perform this task in a background services,how i can achieve this?

My ApplicationA MAinActivity:

```
package com.example.applicationa;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button sendstring;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sendstring = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendstring);

    sendstring.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi Farhan Shah,Welcome to AppB");
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        //  startActivity(sendIntent);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));

        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

This is my ApplicationA Screen Shot:

[image]

When click on button the popup will appear and i am selecting ApplicationB from this popup:

[image]

This is my ApplicationB MainActivty:

```
package com.example.applicationb;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView text_recieve;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    text_recieve = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_recieve);

    // Get intent, action and MIME type
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
            handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
        } else if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
            handleSendImage(intent); // Handle single image being sent
        }
    } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
            handleSendMultipleImages(intent); // Handle multiple images being sent
        }
    } else {
        // Handle other intents, such as being started from the home screen
    }
}

void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
    String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    if (sharedText != null) {
        // Update UI to reflect text being shared
        text_recieve.setText(sharedText);
    }
}

void handleSendImage(Intent intent) {
    Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    if (imageUri != null) {
        // Update UI to reflect image being shared
    }
}

void handleSendMultipleImages(Intent intent) {
    ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    if (imageUris != null) {
        // Update UI to reflect multiple images being shared
    }

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

and This is my ApplicationB menifast file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.applicationb"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

and this the ApplicationB screen shot when i am Receive the the string from ApplicationA:

[image]

**Note:-**

now i want to when i click on button from ApplicationA,complete process will be perform in background services,and when background services is done,then my ApplicationB activity is open with the receiving string,how i can achieve this through services,when click on button the popup will not appear to the user,please some one help me out,Thanks Alot in advance

Comment: Please make your question shorter!

Comment: @ZerO I post a detail question for batter understanding,it is simple to understand kindly review it :)

Comment: Yes, but it is in my opinion far too much detail. I will not read it, because I do not have time to read through all this.

Comment: @ZerO the point of the question is,i am sending string from ApplicationA to ApplicationB,when i calick on a button to AplliationA the popup will appear and i am Selcting ApplicationB from this popup and then i am successfully recieved the string from ApplicationB,now i just want to when i click on button from applicationA the background services run,and no popup appear on the user side,when the process is complete then ApplicationB is open with the recieving String,this is waht is wanted..

Comment: @ZerO hope now u get my point??

Comment: No. Your description is wrong and confusing. You are not sending to another app. You are starting another app. Therefore you use an intent. In the intent you can indeed put a message. To start only your app you have to address your app directly like com.farhan.appb.MainActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my Problem:

my MainActivity from ApplicationA:

```
package com.example.applicationa;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button sendstring;
EditText edit_text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//    startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));

    edit_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

    sendstring = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendstring);

    sendstring.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));


        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

This is my Background Service class:

```
package com.example.applicationa;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
 import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "MyService";
MediaPlayer player;

String et_name;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
//  Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

//  et_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("dealer_id");
    /*
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi Farhan Shah,Welcome to AppB");
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
//  startActivity(sendIntent);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));*/

    /*player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.braincandy);
    player.setLooping(false);*/ // Set looping
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if(intent != null){
         et_name = intent.getStringExtra("et_name");
           }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
//  player.stop();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "" + et_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");

    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setClassName("com.example.applicationb",
            "com.example.applicationb.MainActivity");
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi Farhan Shah,Welcome to AppB");
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(sendIntent);

//  player.start();
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the way to do it. But.... is this nice? It's a service... the user is doing something and suddenly that other app appears. Not nice. That could be done better with just a notification.

Comment: how i can make it batter?

Comment: bro i dont want a notification,prompts etc etc,i just simply want when i click on button the services start and another app display the string and i have done it successfully through background services..

Answer (score 0):

In the intent to start your other app you have to mention its package name like:

```
            intent.setClassName("com.farhan.appb",
                    "com.farhan.appb.MainActivity");
```

Comment: for example when i click on button on applicationA the services start and perform background operation and recieve string in ApplicationB.

Comment: Does not matter if you use a service or what else to initiate it from. If you want that the user is not bothered by android to choose from a list of apps then you have to modify your intent like i showed you.

Comment: but it's not working,and how i can perform this task in background service?

Comment: Well that are two problems. Lets start with the first. Why doesn.t it work? Show the code you tried in onClick() please.

Comment: bro i have solved my problem,Thanks for ur suport :)

Comment: No thanks. But tell how you solved it please. Don't run away like that.